# How to change kafka logs and topic timezone?

Tags: apache-kafka, bitnami

I've deployed Kafka as a Kubernetes pod using bitnami charts.
Kafka version 2.3.0

```
[2020-08-10 16:08:22,515] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_222 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-08-10 16:08:22,515] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2020-08-10 16:08:22,515] INFO Client environment:java.home=/opt/bitnami/java (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
```

I want Kafka logs timestamp and timezone to be in IST not in UTC.